# endpoint made connection to an IP adress the hostname is not resolving to

Tags: dns

Our security product alerted on a possible malicious communication detected by analyzing DNS transactions. The DNS name in question is `www.cyber-sale.net`. I could correlate this even to another event when looking at EDR logs. What surprised me after looking further is the fact the from the EDR logs it looks that this domain got resolved to `52.7.88.0` (note, I'm not surprised that the last octet ends with an 0). When I perform a ping or nslookup on `www.cyber-sale.net` I'm getting two IP's returned that from what I can tell point to AWS Elastic Load Balancing instances:

```
www.cyber-sale.net      canonical name = prod-lp-alb-1655798893.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
Name:   prod-lp-alb-1655798893.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 52.4.230.186
Name:   prod-lp-alb-1655798893.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 34.204.254.77
```

If I perform [URLscan](https://urlscan.io/search/#52.7.88.0) on `52.7.88.0` I can't find the `www.cyber-sale.net` domain.

If I perform `nslookup 52.7.88.0` it returns:

`0.88.7.52.in-addr.arpa  name = ec2-52-7-88-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com.`

If I check on the previous urlscan and search for `ec2-52-7-88-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com` I'm getting hits, and that seams to by one of the servers used by Proofpoint for phishing campaign simulations.

Querying the domain in [OTX AlienVault](https://otx.alienvault.com/indicator/hostname/www.cyber-sale.net) returns 133 passive DNS entries, but never at a point it time did the domain point to `52.7.88.0`, although I'm aware that this data is most likely not complete.

[image: otx alienvault]

None, of the threat intelligence platforms returned any warnings for this. Anyone has an idea how did the client end up connecting to `52.7.88.0` directly? Did it bypass the AWS ELB's?

Comment: *"Anyone has an idea how did the client end up connecting to 52.7.88.0 directly?"* - based on your question this is because *"from the EDR logs it looks that this domain got resolved to 52.7.88.0"*. So there was a DNS lookup for this domain and this resulted in this IP address. Thus the client connected to it. Why the DNS lookup returned this IP - unknown since nothing is known about the DNS server queried. It is likely that the DNS resolved once to this IP globally but it might also be only some specific DNS server returning this value.

Comment: So it's using some kind of AWS load balancer... you are no doubt aware that AWS has *a whole bunch* of IP addresses, right? And these are both AWS IP addresses. If you reverse-lookup your load balancer address you *also* get a compute-1.amazonaws.com DNS name!

Comment: @user253751 you're missing the point. Read the question. Why would it return the IP to which the ELB resolves when the request was for `www.cyber-sale.net` ?

Comment: @newby88 how do you know it did? how do you know that wasn't the IP of the ELB?